# Creating a if/else that appends data from mult. scraped pages if counts differ?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, xpath

I"m trying to scrape Oregon teacher licensure information that looks like [this](http://www.tspc.oregon.gov/lookup_application/LDisplay_Individual.asp?id=535454R3L38) or [this](http://www.tspc.oregon.gov/lookup_application/LDisplay_Individual.asp?id=595R8ZPBL97)(this is publicly available data)

This is my code:

```
for t in range(0,2): #Refers to txt file with ids

    address = 'http://www.tspc.oregon.gov/lookup_application/LDisplay_Individual.asp?id=' + lines2[t]

    page = requests.get(address)

    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

    count = 0 
    for license_row in tree.xpath(".//tr[td[1] = 'License Type']/following-sibling::tr[1]"):
        license_data = license_row.xpath(".//td/text()")
        count = count + 1

        if count==1:
            ltest1.append(license_data)

        if count==2:
            ltest2.append(license_data)

        if count==3:
            ltest3.append(license_data)

with open('teacher_lic.csv', 'wb') as pensionfile:
    writer = csv.writer(pensionfile, delimiter="," )
    writer.writerow(["Name", "Lic1", "Lic2", "Lic3"])
    pen = zip(lname, ltest1, ltest2, ltest3)
    for penlist in pen:
        writer.writerow(list(penlist))
```

The problem occurs when this happens: teacher A has 13 licenses and Teacher B has 2. In A my total count = 13 and B = 2. When I get to Teacher B and count equal to 3, I want to say, "if `count==3` then `ltest3.append(licensure_data)` else if `count==3` and `license_data==''` then `license3.append('')`" but since there's no count==3 in B there's no way to tell it to append an empty set.

I'd want the output to look like this:

[image: Teacher Licensure Info]

Is there a way to do this? I might be approaching this completely wrong so if someone can point me in another direction, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: What about putting the `ltest3.append(license_data)` after the loop then? Since `count==3` will ever reached after the `for` loop ends.. (I still don't understand what the purpose of this `append()` though)

Comment: @har07 After which `for` loop? I'm using `append()` to put the data into lists in order to keep it in specific order. This is the only way I've managed to get this done but there could be other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this but this managed to work pretty well.

I created some blank spaces to fill in when Teacher A has 13 licenses and Teacher B has 2. There were some `error`s that resulted when the `license_row.xpath` got to the `count==3` in Teacher B. I exploited these errors to create the `ltest3.append('')`.

```
for t in range(0, 2): #Each txt file contains differing amounts

    address = 'http://www.tspc.oregon.gov/lookup_application/LDisplay_Individual.asp?id=' + lines2[t]

    page = requests.get(address)

    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

    count = 0

    test = tree.xpath(".//tr[td[1] = 'License Type']/following-sibling::tr[1]")
    difference = 15 - len(test)

    for i in range(0, difference):
        test.append('')

    for license_row in test:
        count = count + 1

        try:
            license_data = license_row.xpath(".//td/text()")

        except NameError:
            license_data = ''
            if license_data=='' and count==1:
                ltest1.append('')
            if license_data=='' and count==2:
                ltest2.append('')
            if license_data=='' and count==3:
                ltest3.append('')

        except AttributeError:
            license_data = ''

        if count==1 and True:
            print "True"
            if count==1:
                ltest1.append(license_data)

        if count==2 and True:
            print "True"
            if count==2:
                ltest2.append(license_data)

        if count==3 and True:
            print "True"
            if count==3:
                ltest3.append(license_data)

        del license_data

    for endorse_row in tree.xpath(".//tr[td = 'Endorsements']/following-sibling::tr"):
        endorse_data = endorse_row.xpath(".//td/text()")
        lendorse1.append(endorse_data)
```